# Slidedown a new layout from top

Tags: android, animation, layout, slidedown, sliding

I have a main layout being hosted by an activity (setContentView method).

I have a button in the layout. I want to be able to click this button and a new layout will slide down from the left/top until the middle of the screen. So, the screen now will have two layouts where one is on top and another one is just beneath it.

This is something like the UI in Android Jelly Bean where you can pull the settings layout down using a touch gesture.

What are the possible implementations?

A method I have tried:

1. add the slide down layout into main.xml but set its visibility to gone
2. when button is clicked, run some code that will set the layout visibility to 
   VISIBLE  and add some animations.
3. the result of this implementation is that this layout will push the rest of the 
   views down in order to have a "squeeze" space for itself which is not
   what I intended to do (see above)

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingBottom="5dp"
       android:paddingTop="5dp" >

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/PR_slidedown"   <---this is the intended slidedown layout
           android:layout_width="8dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:visibility="gone"
           android:orientation="vertical" >
       </LinearLayout>
        ....
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is partially correct, the other part is to host your two layouts in a FrameLayout so they can overlap with each other. Search for FrameLayout in here, there are a lot of example on how to use it.

Or try the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)